# Unabel to submit form data using jersy to mysql database

Tags: mysql, web-services, maven, jersey-2.0

### This is the Database connection java file which will connect to mysql local databse

```
package com.example.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class Database {

    public Connection getConnection() throws Exception 
    {   
        Connection connection = null;
            try
            {
                String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test1";

                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, 
   "root", "root");




            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return connection;
        }
    }
```

## This is the web service file for getting and adding up the candidates using com.perpule/hello/plain to get simple hello message & /getCandidate to get all list of candidates

```
package com.example.webservice;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Request;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;

import org.apache.http.HttpServerConnection;

import com.example.dao.Candidate;
import com.example.model.CandidateManager;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

@Path("/hello")
public class SayHello {


    ArrayList<Candidate> candidateArr= new ArrayList<Candidate>();

     @Context
      UriInfo uriInfo;
      @Context
      Request request;


    @GET
    @Path("/plain")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayHelloPlain()
    {
        return "hello ";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/candidates")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String CandidateList()
    {
        String candidates=null ;

        try {
            candidateArr= new CandidateManager().getCandidates();
            Gson gson=new Gson();
            candidates=gson.toJson(candidateArr);

        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return candidates;
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/addCandidates")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public void submitCandidates(@FormParam("name") String name, 
   @FormParam("pass") String pass,
            @FormParam("phone") String phone, @FormParam("email") String 
     email,@FormParam("city") String city) 


    {
        Candidate candidate =new Candidate();
        candidate.setName(name);
        candidate.setPass(pass);
        candidate.setPhone(phone);
        candidate.setCity(city);
        candidate.setEmail(email);

        CandidateManager candidateManager=new CandidateManager();
        try {


            candidateManager.addCandidates(candidate);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

### Model class

```
package com.example.model;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.example.dao.Access;
import com.example.dao.Candidate;
import com.example.dao.Database;

public class CandidateManager {

    public ArrayList<Candidate> getCandidates() throws Exception
    {
    ArrayList<Candidate> candidateList = new ArrayList<Candidate>();
        Database db= new Database();
    Connection con=db.getConnection();
    Access access=new Access();

    candidateList=access.getCandidates(con);
    return candidateList;

    }

    public void addCandidates(Candidate candidate) throws Exception
    {
//      ArrayList<Candidate> candidateData = new ArrayList<Candidate>();
        Database db= new Database();
        Connection con=db.getConnection();
        new Access().addCandidates(con,candidate);

    }
}
```

### This is the DAO class for execueteQuery purpose : code for addCandidate is here

---

```
package com.example.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Access {

    ResultSet rs=null;
    public ArrayList<Candidate> getCandidates(Connection connection) throws 
    SQLException{


    ArrayList<Candidate> candidateList =new ArrayList<Candidate>();

    String sql="select * from candidate";
    PreparedStatement psmt =connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs=psmt.executeQuery();
    try {
        while(rs.next())
        {
            Candidate candidateObj = new Candidate();
            candidateObj.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            candidateObj.setPass(rs.getString("pass"));
            candidateObj.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
            candidateObj.setPhone(rs.getString("phone"));
            candidateObj.setCity(rs.getString("city"));
            candidateList.add(candidateObj);

        }

    }catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return candidateList;

}


    public void addCandidates(Connection connection, Candidate candidate) 
 throws SQLException
    {

        String sql="insert into candidate values(?,?,?,?,?)";
        try {

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement 
     =connection.prepareStatement(sql);
//      preparedStatement.executeQuery();


            preparedStatement.setString(1, candidate.name);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, candidate.pass);
            preparedStatement.setString(3, candidate.phone);
            preparedStatement.setString(4, candidate.city);
            preparedStatement.setString(5, candidate.phone);
            preparedStatement.execute();
            connection.close();


        }catch (Exception e) {
              System.err.println("Got an exception!");
              System.err.println(e.getMessage());

        }



    }

}
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: m not getting  error but data not getting submitted to database

Comment: I got one error in my code while adding candidates i m using CANDIDATE POJO in that i have set two times candidate.phone to submit data to the database named candidate.... help me out ...... i checked in console it says 404 not found(failed to load resource)